# ESP8266, Twilio doesn't send SMS

Tags: c++, firebase-realtime-database, twilio, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I've been trying to create SMS alarm using Twilio, Firebase and Arduino IDE. Using sensors I am measuring the temperature. If the temperature is higher than a specified value (ESP reads that value from Firebase Realtime Database), a SMS should be sent using twilio. I am also storing the measures in Firebase Realtime Database. The code worked well, until I tried to add the part where it also pushed measurements (temperatures) to Firebase Realtime Database. It even prints in serial that it is connecting to Twilio api, however, I never receive the message.

Here's my code:

```
#/*
 * Twilio SMS and MMS on ESP8266 Example.
 */
 #include "FirebaseArduino.h"
#include "OneWire.h"
#include "DallasTemperature.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <sstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include "twilio.hpp"

// Use software serial for debugging?
#define USE_SOFTWARE_SERIAL 0

// Print debug messages over serial?
#define USE_SERIAL 1

// Your network SSID and password
const char* ssid="SSID";
const char* password = "PASSWORD";

// Find the api.twilio.com SHA1 fingerprint, this one was valid as 
// of July 2020. This will change, please see 
// https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-esp8266-cpp
// to see how to update the fingerprint.
const char fingerprint[] = "BC B0 1A 32 80 5D E6 E4 A2 29 66 2B 08 C8 E0 4C 45 29 3F D0";

// Twilio account specific details, from https://twilio.com/console
// Please see the article: 
// https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/receive-and-reply-sms-and-mms-messages-esp8266-c-and-ngrok

// If this device is deployed in the field you should only deploy a revocable
// key. This code is only suitable for prototyping or if you retain physical
// control of the installation.
const char* account_sid = "SID";
const char* auth_token = "TOKEN";

// Details for the SMS we'll send with Twilio.  Should be a number you own 
// (check the console, link above).
String to_number    = "+55555";
String from_number = "+66666";
String message_body    = "Hello from Twilio and the ESP8266!";

// The 'authorized number' to text the ESP8266 for our example
String master_number    = "+55555";

// Optional - a url to an image.  See 'MediaUrl' here: 
// https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages
String media_url = "";

// Global twilio objects
Twilio *twilio;
ESP8266WebServer twilio_server(8000);

//  Optional software serial debugging
#if USE_SOFTWARE_SERIAL == 1
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// You'll need to set pin numbers to match your setup if you
// do use Software Serial
extern SoftwareSerial swSer(14, 4, false, 256);
#else
#define swSer Serial
#endif

String b;
int c;
#define FIREBASE_HOST ".firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH ""

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 4 
/********************************************************************/
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices  
// (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs) 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
/********************************************************************/
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

float temp1 = 0;

/*
 * Setup function for ESP8266 Twilio Example.
 * 
 * Here we connect to a friendly wireless network, set the time, instantiate 
 * our twilio object, optionally set up software serial, then send a SMS 
 * or MMS message.
 */
void setup() {
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        twilio = new Twilio(account_sid, auth_token, fingerprint);

        #if USE_SERIAL == 1
        swSer.begin(115200);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
                delay(1000);
                swSer.print(".");
        }
        swSer.println("");
        swSer.println("Connected to WiFi, IP address: ");
        swSer.println(WiFi.localIP());
        #else
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) delay(1000);
        #endif

        // Response will be filled with connection info and Twilio API responses
        // from this initial SMS send.
        


        twilio_server.begin();

        // Use LED_BUILTIN to find the LED pin and set the GPIO to output
        pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

         sensors.begin(); 
         Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH); 

}


/* 
 *  In our main loop, we listen for connections from Twilio in handleClient().
 */
void loop() {
  b = Firebase.getString("002/alarm");
  c = b.toInt();
  Serial.print(c);

   sensors.requestTemperatures();
   temp1 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
   StaticJsonBuffer<256> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& timeStampObject = jsonBuffer.createObject();
timeStampObject[".sv"] = "timestamp";

JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
JsonArray& timestamp = root.createNestedArray("timestamp");
timestamp.add(timeStampObject);
JsonArray& temperature = root.createNestedArray("temperature");
temperature.add(temp1);


Firebase.push("Sensors/001", root);
   if (temp1 > c) {
        String response;
        bool success = twilio->send_message(
                to_number,
                from_number,
                message_body,
                response,
                media_url
        );
   }
        

          delay(20000);
}
```

Comment: I know that ESP8266 Sensors are too sensitive, they can broke too easily even you can't notice untill it drives you crazy, so my first advice is change your ESP8266 and try again (if you have). Or; Test your ESP8266 with easy codes that you can be sure its working

Comment: have you added a Serial.print() to verify that the Firebase.push() call is returning?